# how to get id in listview from database in retrofit

Tags: android, listview, retrofit2

i am trying to get id position but it return 0 in all listview.

```
public class Post {

            @SerializedName("id")
            @Expose
            private int id;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
```

here we convert id to string but it return 0

```
holder.tvId.setText(String.valueOf(mContact.get(position).getId()))
```

what should i do properly

Comment: is the ID present in your mContact, have you verfied it

Comment: yes mContact is the varibale of List<post> mContact;

Comment: Are u first add setId property.

Comment: No I am telling did you evaluate your list after initializing it and checked if it has id in it

Comment: when u add mContact.add(your value);

Comment: @MRX yes i initialized it other fields return value but id get 0 in all listview

Comment: please add the code where you are initializing the list object in retrofit response.